# How to can I run adb screenrecord on a Android Device from Java and end the screenrecording?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, adb, threadpoolexecutor

How to can I run `adb shell screenrecord` on a `Android` Device from `Java` and end the `screenrecording`?

Currently I have to specify the `--time-limit` to end the recording.  If I try to capture the video prior to it ending it fails.

Is there a way to tell adb to stop recording?  Is there a way to configure the thread to send a `CTRL-C` to the `shell` command?

This is to be run on unrooted phones.

**Code**

```
videoExecutor.submit(() -> {
          //Start recording video
        String recordVideo = "screenrecord --time-limit " + testRun.getVideoLength() + " " + "/sdcard/" + logDate + ".mp4";
    try {
      device.executeShell(recordVideo);
  } catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
  }
    sleep(testRun.getVideoLength()*ONE_SECOND + TWO_SECONDS);  //gotta match the --time-limit above.

RemoteFile remote = new RemoteFile("/sdcard/" + logDate + ".mp4");
File local = new File(videoPath); //Save file to local machine
          if(!local.getParentFile().exists()) {
              local.getParentFile().mkdirs();
          }

    try {
      //Copy video from phone to computer
        try {
                  device.pull(remote, local);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

      });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending either `SIGINT` or `SIGHUP` to [`screenrecord`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp) process would cause it to stop recording.

I just tried the following on unrooted (stock Android 6.0) phone in 2 separate `adb shell` sessions:

in session #1:

```
screenrecord /sdcard/Movies/test.mpg
```

in session #2:

```
pkill -INT screenrecord
```

and the `screenrecord` capture stopped after issuing the `pkill` command

Comment: The phones are not rooted so it looks like they do not have access to killall.   adb shell killall -q =1 screenrecord /system/bin/sh: killall: not found

Comment: Hey Alex are you referring to killing the process on the server?  I am looking at killing it on the phone.  It looks like unlocked android phones to not have access to kill or killall unless I am missing something?

Thanks

/system/bin/sh: kill: 998: Operation not permitted

Comment: double check your `pid` - there should be no permission issues when trying to send a signal to a process running under the same user id

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly Alex.  Have a great weekend