# How can I redirect android's getevent output to a file?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm trying to redirect the `getevent` command in Android to a file on the device.

I tried. `getevent > /path/to/file`, but that didn't work. When I `CTRL+C`'d, the file was empty.

After further investigation, I discovered that it works if I use `getevent`'s `-c` flag, which tells the process to terminate after a certain number of events are received. This leads me to believe that the problem is related to the fact that I'm killing the process. When I use `tee` instead of a `>`, I can see that the output does not show in stdout until the process finishes gracefully.

The problem of course is that `getevent` never terminates, and I can't use the `-c` flag because I won't know beforehand how many events are going to be received.

How can I redirect the `getevent` to a file in such a way that it is there even when the process is killed?

It's fine if the solution requires the device to be rooted.

Edit: I've discovered through further investigation, that if I ensure that at least 25 events have been sent, it writes to the file. But if I ensure 30 events have been sent, only those 25 events will be written to the file. This confirmed my suspicion, that it's a buffer issue.

Comment: what's your host OS/shell?

Comment: @AlexP. Windows with cmder.

Comment: so what's the reason for `linux` and `bash` tags?

Comment: Does `CTRL+C` bring you back to the `adb` shell or back to your Windows shell?

Comment: It brings me back to the adb shell. I put the linux tag because I think this is probably a more general problem of how to write a command with never ending output to a file.

Comment: you can try this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/38364669/1778421

Comment: just to be clear - the issue you are experiencing is specific to your environment. `getevent` is more than happy to flush the buffer upon receiving the `SIGINT` aka `CTRL+C`

Comment: I think I've been barking up the wrong tree for a while. I think It's being caused by things specific to my project which I can't share on SO. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AlexP. I think I was mistaken yesterday. I've reopened the question. The method you linked to is not working though. I have discovered more information which I will add to the question. If I ensure that at least 25 events have been sent, it will write to the file. But if there are a few more than 25 events, it will only write those 25. Confirming my suspicion that it's a buffer issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to write a script calling getevent -c 1 in a loop.